# How can we remove duplicate folder path using python

Tags: python, url

I am getting this below output when I filter only folder path of the user. Sometimes i am getting more than one path for a particular user as shown below. I have to pass these path another query where i will get its size.
How can i separate the two paths separately and pass to a single url query which calculates the size of the folder.

```
/Users/G/H/gggggg, hhhhhhh
/Users/X/Z/Xxxxxx, Zzzzzzz,/Users/X/B/Z/Xxxxxx, Zzzzzzz
/Users/I/O/iiiiii, ooooooo
/Users/S/A/Solarr, Alann,/Users/S/T/A/Solarr, Alann
```

Comment: Please provide your code and efforts to solve this problem in the question. People here will help you solve your issues in the code. No one will simply write your desired code for you.

Comment: This is unclear. You are asking people to solve this problem, but they are here to help you overcome specific difficulties. What are the difficulties you encountered so far ? Did you try something ?

Answer (score 0):

If your input is string, then you can do something like this:

```
s = "/Users/X/Z/Xxxxxx, Zzzzzzz,/Users/X/B/Z/Xxxxxx, Zzzzzzz"
a = s.split(',')
for p,u in zip(a[:-1:2], a[1::2]):
  print(p.strip(),u.strip()) # here you can call your function with path and user parameters
```

Output:

```
/Users/X/Z/Xxxxxx Zzzzzzz
/Users/X/B/Z/Xxxxxx Zzzzzzz
```